# Uploading .xls file from webserver to Google Drive using PHP code

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have a code which extracts database table into an excel file, now i wish to upload this file to google drive using google-drive-api or something. The only problem i am facing is on how to accomplish the upload process as i want this file to be synced atleast 4 times in a second. 
the code to request the export from database is here. Can someone help me to upload this file(testfile.xls) to Google-Drive?

```
<?php
// All Copyrights owned 2015. Ask Owner before Copying Code.

header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testfile.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

        try { 

            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', "root", "");

            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $db = $db;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {             
            die($e);
        }

        try {

            $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY `event_id` ASC;");
            $query->execute();


            while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                $ret[] = $row;

            foreach ($ret as $key => &$entry) 
                $events[$entry['event_id']][$key] = $entry;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {             
            die($e);
        }

        $event = array('',..........,'Band');

        $tot_num=0;
        foreach($events as $ev)
            {   $event_num=0;
                echo "Time"."\n";
                    foreach($ev as $e) {
                        //Multiple echo Statements
                    }
            echo "\n";
            echo "Event Total: "."\t".$event_num."\n"."\n";
        }

    echo $tot_num;



?>
```

Comment: No, you're not "extracting into an excel file". You're not extracting into any kind of a file. The fact that Excel can load the plain text you're outputting doesn't make it Excel in any way/shape/form.

Comment: @pinoyyid can you help?

 I just need this file to be uploaded to drive and be synced every minute, is that possible?

Comment: @MarcB  The plain text that you are referring to, i changed its format and made it into an excel sheet for better understanding of the database.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easer to just write to a Google sheet that's already on your google drive why are you uploading files?

Comment: @DaImTo I wish to keep syncing a file into my google sheets.
how to accomplish even writting to a google sheet that is already present in my google drive? I tried all the examples of google-api-client-master but i am not able to get any positive result.

Comment: Use this for authentication https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php  use this for file upload. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simplefileupload.php

Comment: tried not uploading :(

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with Google's "API Client Library for PHP (Beta)". They have a specific example to upload a single file. Look the "Simple Upload" section on https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload

Answer (score 0):

By the way i think i found an option,
I used google app script to fetch data from the server as a blob and paste it directly in my drive, this app script could search for existing files, could delete old versions and then push in new files.

```
function downloadFile(fileURL,folder) {

  var fileName = "";
  var fileSize = 0;

     var fileURL="enter url on server where you wish to take data from";
     //Removing files with name "export"
     var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
     'title contains "export"');
     while (files.hasNext()) 
     {
        var file = files.next();
       DriveApp.removeFile(file);
     }
    //Search Folder by name "Backups"

    var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders('title contains "Backups"');
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
     var folder = folders.next();
     var id= folder.getId();
     }

    //URL Fetch and Response log
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
    var rc = response.getResponseCode();
    var fol_id = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    //Creating File
    if (rc == 200) {
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
    if (folder != null) {
      var files= fol_id.createFile(fileBlob);
      var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
      fileName = "Registrations";
      fileSize = file.getSize();
    }
    }

    var fileInfo = { "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize };
    return fileInfo;
    }
```

Note: Be sure to activate Drive API in the script.